# html sitemap via recursive function

Tags: sitemap, recursive

I'm trying to render my page structure as an ordered list (`<ol>`) showing the hierarchy using nested ordered lists. So it should look something like

```
<ol>
  <li>
    About
    <ol>
      <li>
        Leadership
        <ol>
          <li>CEO</li>
          <li>COO</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Products</li>
</ol>
```

**or**

1. About

   1. Leadership

      1. CEO
      2. COO
2. Services
3. Products

I created a function to get 1 level of pages which I call recursively for any pages with child pages.

```
function aiv_get_sibling_pages($cur_page = null) {
    $front_page_id = get_option('page_on_front');
    $next_page = $cur_page ? $cur_page : get_post($front_page_id);

    $out = '';

    $pages_args = array(
        'exclude' => '', /* ID of pages to be excluded, separated by comma */
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'parent' => $next_page -> post_parent
    );
    $pages = get_pages($pages_args);

    $out .= '<ol>';
    foreach($pages as $page) {
        $next_page = $page;

        $out .=  '<li>';
        $out .= $page -> post_title;
        $child_pages = get_pages('child_of=' . $page->ID);
        if(count($child_pages) > 0) {
            $out .= aiv_get_sibling_pages($next_page);
        }
        $out .= '</li>';   
    }
    $out .= '</ol>';

    return $out;
}
```

Everything works as expected until the recursive part: `aiv_get_sibling_pages($next_page);`

This produces the error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /home/anupadmin/example.com/wp-includes/post.php on line 5781`

I'm not entirely sure what that means, but I'm guessing if I'm running out of memory that I'm doing something inefficiently. Can anyone point me towards a better way to do this or shed some light on why I"m getting the error?

### UPDATE

HEre's a cleaned up, working version implementing solution from accepted answer below:

```
function aiv_get_sibling_pages($parent_id = 0) {
    $out = '';
    $pages_args = array(
        'exclude' => '',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'parent' => $parent_id
    );
    $pages = get_pages($pages_args);    
    if($pages) {
        $extra_className = $parent_id > 0 ? ' child-list' : '';
        $out .= '<ol class="sitemap__list--ordered ' . $extra_className . '">';
        foreach($pages as $page) {
            $out .=  '<li class="sitemap__item">';
            $out .= $page -> post_title;
            $out .= aiv_get_sibling_pages($page -> ID);
            $out .= '</li>';   
        }
        $out .= '</ol>';
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: By siblings do you actually mean children aka daughter/child/son pages, or do you mean brothers/sisters adjacent posts? This code isn't very clear and I suspect this is because you've muddled up the terms siblings and children and grabbed adjacent posts, not child posts

Comment: no i mean brothers/sisters. The function is meant to return a list of 1 level of pages at a time based on the parent page, which is passed in the `$cur_page` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "memory exhausted" error in question happened because of this part in your function: `'parent' => $next_page -> post_parent`, which should actually be `'parent' => $next_page -> ID` (or I'd omit the unnecessary spaces, i.e. I'd use `'parent' => $next_page->ID`).

And the error can be illustrated like so:

```
$cur_page = get_post( 123 ); // assume the post_parent is 45
aiv_get_sibling_pages( $cur_page );
// 1. get_pages() is called with 'parent' set to 45.

// 2. Assume get_pages() returned page 123 as the 1st item.
// 3. Your `foreach` calls aiv_get_sibling_pages( <the post object for page 123> )

// 4. .. and then the loop restarts at step 1 and never ends..
// eventually, PHP exits with the "memory exhausted" error :(
```

So as I said earlier, use `'parent' => $next_page->ID` and the memory error would be gone.

But I would also make these changes:

1. *Before* the `$out .= '<ol>';`, add this:

   ```php
   // Don't add the OL if there are no more pages.
   if ( empty( $pages ) ) {
       return '';
   }
   ```
2. The `get_pages()` in the `foreach` is not necessary. So,

   ```php
   // Replace this:
   $child_pages = get_pages('child_of=' . $page->ID);
   if(count($child_pages) > 0) {
       $out .= aiv_get_sibling_pages($next_page);
   }

   // with just:
   $out .= aiv_get_sibling_pages( $next_page );
   ```

#### And actually, you could use [`wp_list_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/)..

Something like this:

```php
$list = wp_list_pages( array(
    'child_of' => 123, // just change 123 to the correct ID
    'title_li' => '',
    'echo'     => false,
) );

echo '<ol>' . str_replace(
    [ '<ul>', '<ul ', '</ul>' ],
    [ '<ol>', '<ol ', '</ol>' ],
    $list
) . '</ol>';
```

But yes, if you want full control over the HTML, then your custom function would be easier in that case.

Comment: YES! I was passing the Post object rather than its ID. Thanks for finding that. And yeah, i started off using `wp_list_pages()`, but the requirements for the display of the lists prompted the need to iterate over each Post, one at a time.

Comment: New, working function added to OP.